# How to implement dataType jsonp to overcome CORS using Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, kendo-grid, jsonp

Update: I do not have control of the code or servers of the API endpoint. That is why I am pursuing this jsonp "hack". My frontend is AngularJS. I also attached a screenshot of the same API call in the 3 different browsers.

I searched all over SO but could not find an answer. My code currently uses Kendo Grid to display some data. See existing code below, the transport portion of the kendo.data.DataSource.

```
transport: {
      read: {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',    //change this to jsonp
        url: baseUrl + '/api/entity/wandcsearch',
        data: {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

The API call works fine in IE. But I need to make it work for Edge and Chrome also. When I fire the same call through my UI. Chrome comes back with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. Did some research and was suggested to change dataType from 'json' to 'jsonp'. Made the change and now the call fires successfully but the Kendo Grid is blank/empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWX6.png)

Comment: Has to be JSONP, right? Have you seen [this doc page](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/basic-usage) and/or [this page](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/cors)? One more [jsonp example from their ref docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/data)

Comment: "The API call works fine in IE. But I need to make it work for Edge and Chrome also" — We can't tell why it works in one but not the others without an [mcve].

Comment: "Did some research and was suggested to change dataType from 'json' to 'jsonp'." — JSONP is what we used a decade ago before CORS was widely supported. You avoid JSONP today. If you do use it, then you need to make sure the server supports it.

Comment: "Made the change and now the call fires successfully but the Kendo Grid is blank/empty." - this means that you have overcome your CORS error and now your problem has nothing to do with CORS at all. You need to go further and find out what response you receive from server and what's happening with it in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

**First** check whether your browser supports CORS - [https://caniuse.com/#feat=cors]

**Second**

> if you're implementing  $.get then you should set  dataType to jsonp.
>
> if You're using $.getJSON then you should included callback=? in the URL.

Comment: "First check whether your browser supports CORS" — It's 2018. Their browser supports CORS … and if they are using JSONP then their browser doesn't need to support CORS.

Comment: what does year have to do with browser version. If its 2019 you expect everyone around the globe to use the latest browser !!!!!

Comment: CORS has been well supported for *many years*. There are no browsers for which security updates are produced which do not support CORS (except those which don't support JS at all). People using browsers which don't support CORS are (a) a statistically insignificant number (b) vulnerable to security problems and need to upgrade anyway.